# DJANGO - Get values from model by join of two tables

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to get all data from a table by a model, i can get all data from the table this works ok, but i need get data from other table mapped by  a foreign key to another table, this means i have a field called ***ID_USUARIO*** in Parcela Model and i want to get all data that have my actual query with the value from the other table called ***FULLNAME*** in Usuario Model.

How can i do that?

Usuario Model

```
class Usuario(Model):
    ID_USER = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    FULLNAME = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    EMAIL = models.EmailField()
    PASSWORD = models.CharField(max_length=450)
```

Parcela Model

```
class Parcela(Model):
    """docstring for Parcela."""

    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ID_USUARIO = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ID_PARCELA = models.BigIntegerField()
    A_DEAD_LEAVES = models.FloatField()
    A_SOIL_DEPTH = models.FloatField()
    A_LIGHT_FUEL = models.FloatField()
    A_DUFF = models.FloatField()
    A_MID_HEA_FUEL = models.FloatField()
    A_SOIL_ROCK_COLOR = models.FloatField()
    B_DOMINANT_VEG_TYPE = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    B_FCOV = models.FloatField()
    B_FOLIAGE_ALTERED = models.FloatField()
    B_FREQ_LIVING = models.FloatField()
    B_NEW_SPROUTS = models.FloatField()
    C_DOMINANT_VEG_TYPE = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    C_FCOV = models.FloatField()
    C_FOLIAGE_ALTERED = models.FloatField()
    C_FREQ_LIVING = models.FloatField()
    C_LAI_CHANGE = models.FloatField()
    D_DOMINANT_VEG_TYPE = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

This is the query i'm doing

```
export = Parcela.objects.select_related('ID_USUARIO')
```

Result of query

```
ID,ID_USUARIO,ID_PARCELA,A_DEAD_LEAVES,A_SOIL_DEPTH,A_LIGHT_FUEL,A_DUFF,A_MID_HEA_FUEL,A_SOIL_ROCK_COLOR,B_DOMINANT_VEG_TYPE,B_FCOV,B_FOLIAGE_ALTERED,B_FREQ_LIVING,B_NEW_SPROUTS,C_DOMINANT_VEG_TYPE,C_FCOV,C_FOLIAGE_ALTERED,C_FREQ_LIVING,C_LAI_CHANGE,D_DOMINANT_VEG_TYPE,D_FCOV,D_GREEN_UNALTERAD,D_BLACK_BROWN,D_FREQ_LIVING,D_LAI_CHANGE,D_CHAR_HEIGHT,E_DOMINANT_VEG_TYPE,E_FCOV,E_GREEN_UNALTERAD,E_BLACK_BROWN,E_FREQ_LIVING,E_LAI_CHANGE,E_CHAR_HEIGHT,COORDINATE_X,COORDINATE_Y,DATE_CAPTURED,DATE_SAVED,PHOTO_1,PHOTO_2,PHOTO_3,PHOTO_4,PHOTO_5,SEVERITY
2,1,1,20.0,30.0,10.0,20.0,15.0,6.0,Cactus,12.0,11.0,13.0,3.0,Pasto,2.0,6.0,2.0,3.1,Arbol,1.2,14.0,8.0,4.0,0.5,2.0,Hongos,3.0,1.9,11.0,10.2,20.1,18.4,624811.32,665561.23,2019-08-27 16:56:20,2019-08-27 16:56:20,,,,,,Moderada
3,1,1,20.0,30.0,10.0,20.0,15.0,6.0,Cactus,12.0,11.0,13.0,3.0,Pasto,2.0,6.0,2.0,3.1,Arbol,1.2,14.0,8.0,4.0,0.5,2.0,Hongos,3.0,1.9,11.0,10.2,20.1,18.4,624811.32,665561.23,2019-08-27 16:56:20,2019-08-27 16:56:20,,,,,,Moderada
4,1,1,20.0,30.0,10.0,20.0,15.0,6.0,Cactus,12.0,11.0,13.0,3.0,Pasto,2.0,6.0,2.0,3.1,Arbol,1.2,14.0,8.0,4.0,0.5,2.0,Hongos,3.0,1.9,11.0,10.2,20.1,18.4,624811.32,665561.23,2019-08-27 22:46:52,2019-08-25 15:46:12,,,,,,Moderada
5,1,2,100.0,2.0,2.1,1.2,1.0,1.1,Margaritas,40.0,0.3,1.25,2.65,Pinos,2.0,6.0,2.0,3.1,Guayacan,1.2,14.0,8.0,4.0,0.5,2.0,Roble,3.0,1.9,11.0,10.2,20.1,18.4,624811.32,665561.23,2019-08-24 22:46:52,2019-08-28 15:46:12,,,,,,Alta
6,2,3,100.0,2.0,2.1,1.2,1.0,1.1,Cedro,40.0,0.3,1.25,2.65,Rosas,2.0,6.0,2.0,3.1,Savila,1.2,14.0,8.0,4.0,0.5,2.0,Eucalipto,3.0,1.9,11.0,10.2,20.1,18.4,624811.32,665561.23,2019-08-24 22:46:52,2019-08-28 15:46:12,,,,,,No Quemada
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing it correctly. One must use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to do join in django. you can verify the generated query

```
result = Parcela.objects.select_related('ID_USUARIO')
print(str(result.query))
# You can access ID_USARIO fields like this
print(result.first().ID_USARIO.FULLNAME)
```

To get rows in parcela table with a name, you can do [reverse lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward). Then the query will be

```
result = Usuario.objects.get(FULLNAME='<name_to_filter>')
parcela_rows = result.parcela_set.all()
```

Comment: ok got it, can get the value.... but if I want add the FULLNAME of the user to my query, how can I do that?, because I need return all data from Parcela Table with the user name.